# "apt upgrade" over SSH: This frontend requires a controlling tty

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, debian, upgrade, apt

When upgrading our linux servers, I issue a command like this from one of our management servers:

```
ssh server1.mycompany.com apt upgrade
```

Under certain circumstances, I get this output from the command:

```
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
```

As I don't get to interact with the dialog, I guess the defaults are chosen. 
How do other people deal with this issue? Logging into each server to run apt upgrade, just in case a dialog pops up, doesn't sound like the way to go. Maybe there's a way to abort the "apt upgrade" or something when dialogues pops up? Or even better, maybe there's a way to get the popup to be displayed on the client side of the SSH connection, i.e. on the server I'm ssh'ing *from*?

Comment: Have you looked into the `-t` option to ssh?

Comment: @EugenRieck has the right answer here I think, I overcome the same issue when trying to sudo a command as above by using the -t flag.

Answer (score 2):

You need a terminal, which you may set either via the parameters of
`-t` which forces a pty or `-T` which forces no pty (or the corresponding config file options).

Further, when using a pty the `TERM` environment variable is copied (exceptions may apply check documentation for completed details and official sweepstakes entry form).

You may specify the noninteractive front-end which has no requirements and
does not ask any questions (which may or may not be what you want) :

```
ssh <remote_srv> "DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get autoremove"
```

For more information see the Ask Ubuntu post
[Unable to initialize frontend: dialog when using ssh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506158/unable-to-initialize-frontend-dialog-when-using-ssh).